# Deploy a local Add-ins for Outlook with signing signature or dll

Tags: deployment, vsto, visual-studio-2019, outlook-addin, setup-deployment

Edit:

With the reply from Dmitry Streblechenko, looks like my only option is to created a dll that I can manually installed. May I know how can I do that?

I converted my Outlook vba macro to a VSTO add-ins so that I can shall with my co-workers. I only need it to work on the desktop version. I use Vistal Studio 2019 and managed to deploy it "from CD-ROM or DVD-ROM". The code is signed with a key issued by my company for code signing purpose.

My co-worker is able to install the add-ins by running the setup.exe generated. All is well and no warning message generated, i.e. it is trusted because the code is signed. However, when we looked at Windows 10 [Apps and features](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgPDw.jpg), the name of my company does not show, like you would see "Microsoft Cooperation" for Microsoft app.

I need to have the company name shown so that my IT would not forcefully remove the add-ins.

An alternative is to create a dll for manually insert it in Outlook. I look at the files produced by the Publish Wizard, there isn't any dll that I can use.

Q: How can I have my company name shown so that IT knows this add-ins is signed by a certificate issued by iur company, or how can I generate a dll to avoid the installation process?

Answer (score 0):

The company name comes form the installer, not from a signing certificate. E.g. if you are using WiX to create the installer, that would be the `Manufacturer` attribute of the `Project` node in your WXS file.

Comment: Thanks... Looks like this is not the way forward for me since it still does not show that this is an "authorized" app.

Comment: There is no such thing as "authorized" app.